# $http() is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax

```js
 Enter Where Condition: <input type="text" id="myText">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Go</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction($http) {
    var condition = document.getElementById("myText").value;
        $http({

            method: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost:8080/peter/peter1/where",
            params: {"where":condition},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

            });
        } 

    <script/>
```

When i tried to debug the above code i am getting an error saying that 
    $http is not a function... In the above code i am getting error 
    saying $http is not a function..please help me in resolving this problem...

Comment: What javascript library are you including that should define the $http function?

Comment: are you using angular js, other wise how can you use $http, is it your defined variable ?

Comment: i am using angularjs

Comment: `</script>` not `<script/>` - `<button onclick="myFunction()">` you don't pass anything to the function so the argument is undefined

Comment: I think that you need to know how angular works first https://angularjs.org/

Comment: ya when i editing the code in stackoverflow i commiter that mistake @AlexK.

Comment: You should really look into angularjs first, as Wilfredo P suggested. Your function should go into a controller that goes into your angular application, and should be called with ng-click.

Comment: i tried that too its giving me an error myFunction is not defined@RedSonja

Comment: Have a look at the example in Dwardu's anwser. You have to create a module for your application, append a controller and inject the stuff you need ($http and $scope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is a service you can inject when using [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/).

What you have in your code right now won't work because you defined a function which expects an argument called `$http`, which you haven't passed.

On top of this it expects that `$http` argument is a function that accepts an object presumably to post data to a server.

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/vjsae4Ln/) of how to do what you are trying to do in Angular.

Here is an [Angular Tutorial](https://egghead.io/articles/new-to-angularjs-start-learning-here) by egghead.io which I quite like

Answer (score 0):

```
Enter Where Condition: <input type="text" id="myText">
<button onclick="myFunction($my_http)">Go</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction($http) {
var condition = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost:8080/peter/peter1/where",
        params: {"where":condition},
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

        });
    } 

<script/>
```

Notice that when you are calling the function myFunction() it should be called with a parameter containing an $http Object, like so:

```
myFunction($http_example);
```

AND NOT like so:

```
myFunction();
```